# How do I get the full Assets URL from Low Variables?

Tags: assets, low-variables

I'm having trouble getting the full URL to an image using Low Variables and Assets.

Using the short name of the variable just returns the file name without the rest of the path. `{lv_my_image}` renders as `image.jpg` not `http://site.com/images/image.jpg`.

I've tried several ways to do this.

```
{lv_my_image} = image.jpg
{lv_my_image:url} = {lv_my_image:url}

{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_my_image"}
  {url} = *nothing is returned*
  {assets:url} = {assets:url}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out my problem was the `{exp:low_variables:pair}` tag was nested in a `{exp:channel:entries}` tag. To fix this you have to use the `var_prefix=""` parameter.

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_my_image" var_prefix="assets"}
  {assets:url}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

With this syntax you can access all of the Assets' tags.

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_my_image" var_prefix="assets"}
  <img src="{assets:url}" width="{assets:width}" height="{assets:height}" alt="{assets:alt_text}">
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```