# Assets in Grid In Low Variables - multiple files

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, grid, low-variables, low

EE 2.10.1
Lv 2.6.1
Assets 2.6

I've got a Low Variables grid with a once cell Assets and in the assets you can upload multiple images.

Using [this thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15590/assets-field-inside-of-a-grid-inside-of-a-low-variable-asset-not-saving) I was able to successfully display a single image, but there is no way to loop through the assets to pull up all files.

My current partially working code looks like this where title, image, and copy or cells in the grid.:

```
        {exp:low_variables:pair var="lv-deal-sidebar-widget"}
            <aside>
                <h3>{lv-deal-sidebar-widget:title}</h3>

                {exp:ce_img:single src="{lv-deal-sidebar-widget:image:url}" width="300" height="240" crop="yes" attributes="class='img-responsive'"}

                <div class="widget-copy">
                    {lv-deal-sidebar-widget:copy}
                </div><!-- /.widget-copy -->
            </aside>
        {/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

If I try to get more than one image using [this thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/8969/how-do-i-get-the-full-assets-url-from-low-variables) as a guide and this simplified code:

```
        {exp:low_variables:pair var="lv-deal-sidebar-widget" var_prefix="assets"}
            <aside>

                <p>{lv-deal-sidebar-widget:image:url}</p>

                {assets:image}
                    {assets:url} <br />
                {/assets:image}

            </aside>
        {/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

the assets pair doesn't render it just outputs the code as is. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I reported this bug to Pixel & Tonic, and they right away got working on a "duct-tape" type fix. It seems, to get this working, in Assets 2.6, you can change line `1810` of `system/expressionengine/third_party/assets/ft.assets.php` from

```
if (! $field_name)
```

to

```
$tagparts = ee()->TMPL->tagparts;
if (! $field_name || (isset($tagparts[0]) && $tagparts[0] == 'low_variables'))
```

and then in your template, you need to use the `var_prefix` parameter, and then put that prefix BEFORE everything else in your variable, and it should look something like this:

```
{homepage_slider:images var_prefix="image"}
    <img src="{image:homepage_slider:images:url}" />
{/homepage_slider:images}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Will try this later, but hope it gets added to a new assets build soon. Not a fan of using hacks.

Answer (score 1):

When using the Parse or Pair tag to output a Grid field, the tag will act the same as a regular Channel Grid field would. That means you can use the same [template tags and parameters](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/grid.html#template-tags). That means the `var_prefix` parameter won't do anything, because it's not a valid Grid parameter.

It also means you need to prefix all Grid columns with the field/var name. So rather than using `{assets:image}{/assets:image}`, you should use what you're already using with the `title` column: `{lv-deal-sidebar-widget:image}{/lv-deal-sidebar-widget:image}` (assuming `image` is the name of the Assets column in Grid).

That, in turn, will act the same as a regular Assets field, so you should be able to use [any of its template tags](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/field.html).

**Edit:** To illustrate:

```
{!-- a LV Grid with Assets column --}
{exp:low_variables:pair var="my_grid_var"}
    {my_grid_var:assets_column_name var_prefix="foo"}
        {foo:my_grid_var:assets_column_name:url}
    {/my_grid_var:assets_column_name}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}

{!-- an Assets var --}
{exp:low_variables:pair var="my_assets_var"}
    {url}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't work. If I use the tag pair you posted with {url} in the middle front end outputs two {url}{url} but it's not the url just the code. same if I use {image:url} but if I put {lv-deal-sidebar-widget:image:url} then I get one url not two as expected.

Comment: The fact that it spits out two `{url}` vars tells me the loop does work, but you just need to get the variable naming right. See my examples that I just added. Perhaps that sheds some light. Also note that LV is not responsible for parsing the Grid/Assets vars. It just calls their functions and returns what they return.

Comment: copied exactly what you have and it's still outputting {foo:url} twice  See this pastie http://pastie.org/10689796

Comment: Well, it was untested. ;) Ask P&T.

Comment: Try again with the updated code.

Comment: Actually not 100% there, outputs two urls but it's the first url twice not the second one

Comment: Aaand try again. If that doesn't work, it's up to P&T.

Comment: that didn't work, I'd already tried before you posted. In anycase I tweeted this thread to P&T. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Argh! I'm having this same issue. Any luck getting it resolved, @CreatSean ?

Comment: Not yet - I can get more than one image displaying but it's the first image repeating. not image 1, image 2